# Using a Wrapper for memory management in c++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Could anyone tell me why i get a compiling error in the "setFlyBehaviour" and "setQuackBehaviour" of the Duck class? (error : "term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments")

this is an example of a strategy pattern from Head First Design Patterns (which is in Java that i translated here in C++). I introduced a Wrapper pattern in order to manage memory. (the wrapper class i'm using is from Mark Joshi, Option Pricing and Design Patterns)

Thanks!!!!!

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>    
#include <math.h>   
#include <string>   
#include <map>  
#include <exception>    
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template< class T>
class Wrapper
{
//Taken From Mark Joshi, Designs patterns and derivatives pricing 
public:

    Wrapper()
    { DataPtr =0;}

    Wrapper(const T& inner)
    {
        DataPtr = inner.clone();
    }
    Wrapper(const Wrapper<T>& original)
    {
        if (original.DataPtr !=0)
            DataPtr = original.DataPtr->clone();
        else
            DataPtr=0;
    }
    ~Wrapper()
    {
        if (DataPtr !=0)
            delete DataPtr;
    }

    Wrapper& operator=(const Wrapper<T>& original)
    {
        if (this != &original)
        {
            if (DataPtr!=0)
                delete DataPtr;

            DataPtr = (original.DataPtr !=0) ? original.DataPtr->clone() : 0;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    T& operator*()
    {
        return *DataPtr; 
    }

    const T& operator*() const
    {
        return *DataPtr; 
    }

    const T* const operator->() const
    {
        return DataPtr;
    }

    T* operator->()
    {
        return DataPtr;
    }
private:
    T* DataPtr;
};


/*****************************************************/
/*****************      Interfaces    ****************/
/*****************************************************/
class FlyBehaviour
{
    private:
    public:
        virtual void fly() const = 0;
        virtual FlyBehaviour* clone() const = 0;
};

class QuackBehaviour
{
    private:
    public:
        virtual void quack() const = 0;
        virtual QuackBehaviour* clone() const = 0;
};

/*****************************************************/
/*****************      Implementations    ***********/
/*****************************************************/

// -- FlyBehaviour

class FlyWithWings : public FlyBehaviour
{
    public:
        virtual void fly() const{
            cout << "flying with wings" << endl;
        }
        virtual FlyBehaviour* clone() const {
            return new FlyWithWings;
        }
};

class FlyNoWay : public FlyBehaviour
{
    public:
        virtual void fly() const{
            cout << "flying no way" << endl;
        }
        virtual FlyBehaviour* clone() const {
            return new FlyNoWay;
        }
};

// -- QuackBehaviour

class Quack : public QuackBehaviour
{
    public:
        virtual void quack() const{
            cout << "Quacking here!" << endl;
        }
        virtual QuackBehaviour* clone() const{
            return new Quack;
        }
};

class Squeak : public QuackBehaviour
{
    public:
        virtual void quack() const{
            cout << "Squeaking here!" << endl;
        }
        virtual QuackBehaviour* clone() const{
            return new Squeak;
        }
};

class Duck
{
    private:
        Wrapper<FlyBehaviour>   flyBehaviour;
        Wrapper<QuackBehaviour> quackBehaviour;

    public:
        void performQuack() const{
            quackBehaviour->quack();
        }
        void performFly() const{
            flyBehaviour->fly();
        }

        void setFlyBehaviour(const FlyBehaviour& mfly){
            flyBehaviour(mfly);
        }
        void setQuackBehaviour(const FlyBehaviour& mquack){
            quackBehaviour(mquack);
        }

        virtual void display() const{
        }
};

class MallardDuck : public Duck
{
    public:
        virtual void display() const{
            cout << "It looks like a Mallar" << endl;
        }
};

class RedheadDuck : public Duck
{
    public:
        virtual void display() const{
            cout << "It looks like a Redhead" << endl;
        }
};



int main()
{

}
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us what errors you actually get. Please edit your question to include the complete and unedited error output.

Comment: Instead of trying to replicate something applicable to other languages and purposes, check the classes *already* available to C++, like auto_ptr (already deprecated), unique_ptr (a better auto_ptr) and references.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there is a point in learning the basic programming principles; that is why students are still taught sorting algorithms even if they are usually already implemented in most major languages

Comment: @SJuan76 thanks, that's exactly why i'm doing this :)

Comment: @SJuan76 indeed there is but they should study those that are considered good implementations. This specific wrapper was written when smart pointers were the new thing - many issues were discovered and fixed in the last 7 years. It's better to learn how the <memory> header works and why, than get confused with an old implementation

Comment: i updated with the error message

Comment: @JasBeck then check the *modern* implementations, that you will be using in actual code. There are a lot of "smart pointers" available in <memory> that cover many cases not covered by this wrapper

Comment: Moreover, the code in this book isn't exactly original - it's based on code that was found in C++-specific books and magazines back then, including Scott Meyers' books on Effective C++ and the (now closed) C++ Users Journal. Check Meyers' "Effective" books on the how and whys of smart pointers. Why are the operators the way they are and what are the implications? What does ownership transfer mean and why should you care?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were actually trying to call non-existent function instead of constructor.
There was also mistake in argument you were passing to setQuackBehaviour.

This should work:

```
    void setFlyBehaviour(const FlyBehaviour& mfly){
        flyBehaviour = mfly;
    }
    void setQuackBehaviour(const QuackBehaviour& mquack){
        quackBehaviour = mquack;
    }
```

Comment: i only overloaded the "=" to take a Wrapper argument.

Comment: You also made constructor taking T, which can do the casting.

Comment: i tried this option but doesn't work :/ source_file.cpp(163) : error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const FlyBehaviour' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
        source_file.cpp(37): could be 'Wrapper<QuackBehaviour> &Wrapper<QuackBehaviour>::operator =(const Wrapper<QuackBehaviour> &)'
        while trying to match the argument list '(Wrapper<QuackBehaviour>, const FlyBehaviour)'

Comment: You are mixing types again - QuackBehaviour with FlyBehaviour

Comment: that works yes!!!! i just need to know why it does work !! how does the compiler know that it can cast from the wrapped object to the wrapper? thank you

Comment: Constructor taking just one parameter, and not declared with explicit keyword is called "converting constructor". Long story short, it allows you to implicitly cast from one type to another.
In your code it is "Wrapper(const T& inner)" that makes this possible. Also, if my (or someone else's) answer is helpful to you, feel free to upvote/accept them. It will also show other users, that your problem has already been solved.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because `Wrapper` does not provide function call operator:

```
R T::operator ()(Arg1 a1, Arg2 a2, …)
```

And you are trying to make a call to `Wrapper` template:

```
flyBehaviour(mfly);
```

Comment: i thought that i was using the constructor on that line!, so written like that doesn't call the constructor of Wrapper class?

Comment: i see your point. but what is the reason that it doesn't call the constructor in this case? how can i adapt that in order to call the constructor intead of the non-implemented operator ()?

Comment: @JasBeck how you can call to constructor when the object is already constructed at that time? You can call to constructor when you first declare the object or in a initialization list.

Comment: that is right! so how can i call the constructor by a setter method in this case? thanks

Comment: @JasBeck just implement method `reset()` for `Wrapper` like it is done in `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

@werewindle like this ?

```
void reset(const QuackBehaviour& original){
        if (DataPtr!= &original)
        {
            if (DataPtr!=0)
                delete DataPtr;

            DataPtr = (original.DataPtr !=0) ? original.DataPtr->clone() : 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: I think it should accept T& as a parameter. But it is up to you. BTW, If you started to write answer to your own question, you should format it is as a proper answer then.